# H5P sending results to Moodle

Tags: moodle, h5p

I am very much puzzled about using H5P in Moodle.
The idea is great, obviously, yet I cannot make it work as **I** expected.

My principles/idea:

- There are bunch of activities in each course
- Each activity can build up several Student's skills, say Creative Thinking or Problem Solving
- After finishing each activity Student, *based on the result*, can go
  to the next activity or re-do it if failed
- For the testing purposes I set up 3 outcomes (0-30 > `NO pass`, 30-70 >
  `1 point`, 71-100 > `2 points`) in the H5P module - this one is working
  fine.
- The outcome should be passed to Moodle, so the course can then decide
  what to do: pass with 1 or 2 points, or fail and request to do the
  activity again
- This outcome then will be added to Student's skillset

Say, I have this basic crossword. After finishing it the Student can achieve two Skills mentioned above yet still this depends on the outcome, eg. result `1` means 0 in Creative Thinking and +1 in Problem Solving, and/or `2` means +1 in Creative Thinking and +2 in Problem Solving.

The activity itself works as expected, as I mentioned above, see the images (note ONE point circled):
[image] and [image], but then nothing happens.

The student is NOT taken to the next activity, all s/he can do is to retry same activity over and over again.

**Is it possible to force Moodle/H5P to act as described above?**

For the testing purposes I used two 'activities': one being 'h5p' itself and the other being 'lesson' with same h5p modules being added inside, see the image:

[image]

I run this all on WAMP
I tried to follow xAPI https://h5p.org/documentation/x-api

[image]

which resulted in js error:

[image]

Sorry for the long post - tried to cover everything.
If anybody knows the answers - this reply will be much appreciated.

Cheers,
Greg